# Como faço para retornar somente uma chaves em uma lista de dicionários?

Tags: python

Por exemplo eu quero somente o returno do "dia" e do "numero_detalhe"

```
[{
    "numero_detalhe": "10231189115600000000001100000000000000000500201120122025000000000",
    "referencia": "02311891156",
    "valor": "0000000000000500",
    "ano": 2012,
    "mes": 11,
    "dia": "20",
    "hora": "20",
    "minuto": "25",
    "segundo": "00",
    "id_transaccao": "0000000"
  },
  {
    "numero_detalhe": "10232832112900000000006600000000000000000500201120122020000000000",
    "referencia": "02328321129",
    "valor": "0000000000000500",
    "ano": 2012,
    "mes": 11,
    "dia": "20",
    "hora": "20",
    "minuto": "20",
    "segundo": "00",
    "id_transaccao": "0000000"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Para isso você pode utilizar compreensão de listas e dicionários:

```py
from typing import List, Dict, Any


def extract(items: List[Dict[str, Any]], keys: List[str]) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
  """ Extrai colunas de uma lista de dicionários.

  Argumentos:
  - items: lista de dicionários original
  - keys: lista com o nome das colunas que deseja extrair

  Retorno:
  - Uma nova lista de dicionários possuindo apenas as colunas desejadas. Se uma
    coluna for informada em `keys` e não existir nos dicionários, ela será ignorada.
  """
  return [
    {key: value for key, value in item.items() if key in keys}
    for item in items
  ]
```

Ou seja, retorne uma nova lista que para cada item da lista original crie um novo dicionário apenas com as chaves desejadas.

Isso é o que chamamos de compreensão de listas:

```
[
  ...
  for item in items
]
```

E isso é a compreensão de dicionário:

```
{key: value for key, value in item.itens if key in keys}
```

A saída dessa função para o seu exemplo seria:

```
[
  {
    "numero_detalhe": "10231189115600000000001100000000000000000500201120122025000000000",
    "dia": "20"
  },
  {
    "numero_detalhe": "10232832112900000000006600000000000000000500201120122020000000000",
    "dia": "20"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dia            = [x["dia"]            for x in lista_de_dicionarios]
numero_detalhe = [x["numero_detalhe"] for x in lista_de_dicionarios]
```

`dia` e `numero_detalhe` serão listas contendo os valores extraídos de `lista_de_dicionarios`. Se nem todos os dicionários na lista tiverem a chave que você quer extrair:

```
dia            = [x.get("dia", None)            for x in lista_de_dicionarios]
numero_detalhe = [x.get("numero_detalhe", None) for x in lista_de_dicionarios]
```

Isso retornará `None` quando a chave não for encontrada no dicionário. Se quiser descartar os dicionários que não tiverem as chaves que você procura, adicione essa linha antes do código:

```
chaves = ["dia","numero_detalhe"]
lista_de_dicionarios = [x for x in lista_de_dicionarios if all([c in x.keys() for c in chaves])]
```